# tabulations are printed as spaces, python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a .csv to .txt file with a special format.

This format includes a line number followed by the necessary information.

```
f.write("1\tsp=1000\n2\tsc=5\n3\tw=1\n4\trepeat:\n")

print(("1\tsp=1000\n2\tsc=5\n3\tw=1\n4\trepeat:\n"))
1   sp=1000
2   sc=5
3   w=1
4   repeat:
```

here's what I'd like and the print confirms that my syntax is correct as I expected but here's the result in my .txt I have space instead of tabs.

txt capture :

[image: txt capture]

unfortunately this file is a setpoint file for a device and it can't read it with spaces

Comment: there is `\n` in the write string can be replaced by \t to make it tabs.

Comment: it showing spaces but when reading the file it's giving the tab only `1\tsp=1000\n2\tsc=5\n3\tw=1\n4\trepeat:\n`. check once

Comment: this looks like an Editor that displays your file. Make sure the editor does not have a "Tab to Spaces" conversion active that converts the tabs your wrote into the file to spaces.

Comment: @LeoArad 
the \n is necessary because each instruction must be given under a new line. 
These three lines are header lines and then a loop adds the values read in the .csv that's why I added a \n at the end.

Comment: @PatrickArtner tabs to space is disable. and i tried 2 different text editor problem is the same on both